# Graph API: How to get outlook categories of other user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get user categories: displayname and color list by Graph API.

GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/outlook/masterCategories. [Microsoft API doc site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/outlookuser-list-mastercategories?view=graph-rest-1.0)

I can get login user's category, but cannot get other user's category.
Because 'Access is deny' error occard.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "date": "2018-12-13T00:04:50"
        }
    }
}
```

I set MailboxSettings.Read Permission. And login user can view other user's appointment and it's color in OWA.

Comment: Are you sure you can get other user's appointment and it's color in their mailbox? Or just the appointment contains you?

Comment: In OWA, i can see other user's shared calender and colored appointments. So i think i have enough exchange permission.

Comment: @Yuki did you ever figure this out?  The API docs say it is possible, shows for personal and user

GET /me/outlook/masterCategories
GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/outlook/masterCategories

But I also get the error even after adding the permissions.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We are having the same problem.